# How to add text bar at the top of a cowplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, cowplot

I have a stuckplot of several plots made using cowplot function in ggplot.
I want to add an "header", a boxed text at top of the cowplot.
They should be five box, with each box length that follow a precise range of time, which is showed only in the bottom plot x axis.

I tried with annotate on the the cowplot, but I can't see nothing.
I have tried with random coordinates for each annotate, just to try.
Than, I don't know how to box the text.

I share two pics:
1) One of my cowplot without the "header"
[image]
2) A pic of an example plot, similar to the plot that i wish
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add this 'header panel' with `cowplot`. You could make a `tableGrob` using the package `grid` and then combine that with another graph through `cowplot::ggdraw()`. But that is unnecessary.

Its much easier to customize such an annotation in `ggplot` itself and then combine everything at the end.

First we make a data frame for the header banner:

```
library(ggplot2)
rects <- data.frame(x=c(0,2,4), xmax=c(2,4,5), y=c(42, 42, 42), z=c("Flowering", "Fruiting", "Ripening"))
```

Then we can annotate some plot. Note here that I am setting the limits for x and y axes to match the `rects` data frame (or the other way around).

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="white") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 50)) +
# add tiles
  geom_rect(data=rects, aes(xmin=x, ymin=40, ymax=45, xmax=xmax, fill=z), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
# add labels
  geom_text(data=rects, aes(x=x, y=y, label=z), hjust=0, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Should get something like this:

[image]

From here its easy to change this banner, map different colors to the fill aesthetic, and so on. Finally, you combine this pre-annotated plot with the rest in `cowplot`.

Comment: So, you say that I could add an annotation at the top of the first plot of the cowplot?
Ok, and how can I regolate the x axis spacing? 
For example, in my first plot I don't have a x, just 3 points!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your x axis appears to be continuous?

Comment: you should be able to do this with the `show.legend` argument, e.g., geom_rect(..., show.legend = FALSE). Same for `geom_text`.

Comment: The x-axis position for the label can be independent of the coordinates for the boxes. You just need another column in the `rects` data frame that has x coordinate for labels. Then use that for plotting of the labels.

Comment: Ok.
I've almost done everything.
The last one: How can I put this text and rect on te top, outside of the plot grid? I want to avoid to have this text under the legend.

Comment: if the legend is `theme(legend.position="top")` you could instead do `theme(legend.position=c(x=0.2, y=0.8), legend.direction="horizontal")` and adjust the y coordinate for the legend so that its below the banner.

Comment: Yes, of course.
I've done in this way.

Thank you so much for your help!!!